# How to insert a variable in a countif formula in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, countif

I’m trying to do a `COUNTIF` function, using `mcol` and `mrow` as variables.
It perfectly works,the problem appears as far I need to increase each time `mrow` value by 1, but the row range R[] in `=COUNTIF(Analysis!RC[9]:R[8]C[9],""<=3"")` to increase each time by 9.

I was thinking to punt into `COUNTIF` another variable `i` and into `for` to put `i = i + 9`, but I’m not sure how to fix it.
Could anyone help with it, please?

```
Sub Test()
    Set wb = Workbooks("Book1.xlsm")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    LastRow0 = Sheets("Tests").Range("A" & Sheets("Tests").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    mcol = 3

    For mrow = 2 To LastRow0
        Cells(mrow, mcol + 1) = "=COUNTIF(Analysis!RC[9]:R[8]C[9],""<=3"")"
        Cells(mrow, mcol + 2) = "=COUNTIF(Analysis!RC[9]:R[8]C[9],""good"")"
    Next mrow

End Sub
```

Comment: You want that the 9 in `RC[9]` to be increased by 9 each time ?

Comment: Not really, column does not change, but the row number yes. For example, first time the row range should be 2:10, then 11:19, etc. with the same columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not clear to me what you want to increase by how much. That will not be a big programming problem, so I leave that to you. I'll show how to construct the formula using variables.

You create the formula as a string, so you will use string operations to construct it.

```
Dim s As String                   ; for the demo, this receives the formula string
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer    ; these are the variables we will use
....                              ; use them in loops, increment them as you need
s = "=COUNTIF(Analysis!RC[" & Trim(Str(i)) & "]:R[" & Trim(Str(j)) & "]C[" & Trim(Str(i)) & "],""<=3"")"
```

The `Str` function converts an integer to a string. The `Trim` function removes the leading space that `Str` put there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Adding two For cycles, i've fixed it, using Your method: formula as a string with variables